# How to load javascript files using google.load instead of directly using tag in freemarker template language?

Tags: javascript, freemarker, google.load

How to load javascript files using google.load instead of directly using  tag in freemarker template language?

Answer (score 3):

For loading common JavaScript Libraries like jQuery, Prototype, MooTools, Dojo... from the Google CDN, you can find more information [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/).

Answer (score 0):

And complementing CMS' answer: this is [the detailed documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#DetailedDocumentation).